# How can we get Local Notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to add notification based on a user defined time and date. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.alertBody = @"HI";
[notif setFireDate:DATE];// fire the notification in ten minutes
notif.alertAction = @"View";
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is explained in the fine [documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Setup a `UILocalNotification` and schedule it with `scheduleLocalNotification:` of `UIApplication`.